# Make GridView AutGenerateColumn a LinkButton that fires RowCommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Simple question which my searches seem to be coming up blank on.

I have a GridView that is `AutoGeneratingColumns=True`

This generates a column "MyColumn". I would like to make this columns value a clickable LinkButton that fires the RowCommand event of the GridView with a specific CommandNmae and the cells value as the CommandArgument.

I'm trying to do this without using a custom ItemTemplate, I know how to do that. I'm hoping i can pragmatically modify a auto generated column in the GridView as described.

Tia

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the current row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ///create a new linkbutton
        LinkButton button = new LinkButton();
        button.Text = "LinkButton";
        button.CommandArgument = "MyArgs";

        //assign a command to the button
        button.Command += Button_Command;

        //add the button to cell x
        e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Because you are adding control dynamically, the binding of the GridView should NOT be wrapped inside an `IsPostBack` check. Something you would do normally.

Comment: How would i handle this if my GridView is is being bound on a button click even (on the previous screen)?

Comment: You will have to "store" the click somewhere, like in a Session. So when the page is reloaded you can execute the same code as you would the button click.